# Simultanous application for extension of residency permit while changing apartment, possible?

Tags: germany, residency

A friend of mine is an exchange student who will soon need an extension of the residency permit but will settle to a new apartment (within the same city region!). She will receive the confirmation only at the end of the month and would register (Ummeldung) then. The problem is, that the residency permit will fall into invalidation a month after.

The phone line at the bureau for foreigners constantly shuts down (we tried on different phones) and does not respond during opening hours. How should the documents be submitted? The change of department and extension of residency permit operate in different departments according the cities' website. Can both transaction occur in the same department? (Bürgerbüro and Ausländerbüro)

Can she apply for extension of residency permit before doing the "Ummeldung", if yes, should she specify the old or upcoming address?

Comment: Ask the Bürgerbüro when you do the Anmeldung, since this differs from state to state. If an online appointment is required, look if both services are offered. If yes, select both.